# Get frequency band of cellular network android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get frequency band number assigned to the mobile programmatically in android. For example, frequency number while taking on a phone, or connected to the internet(not wifi) using mobile internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know so far, you cannot get the spercial band number **BUT** you can get the network name like GPRS or EDGE, HSDPA and many other:

```
public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(info==null || !info.isConnected())
            return "Not connected!";
        if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return "Wifi";
        if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            // this will return on of EDGE, LTE, HSDPA and many other
            return info.getSubtypeName();
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }
```